# Getting Error: "Undefined Variable : var" when passing a variable into a Octobercms closure function

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have looking a way to pass a variable inside a http client method. For example :

```
$response_send_email = Http::get('some url',function($http){
   $http->data(['id'=>$var]);
});
```

I have tried to pass the variable, but it always showed an error **"Undefined Variable : var"**. Before that, I have tried another way like this and it works :

```
$response_send_email = Http::get('some url',function($http){
       $http->data(['id'=>1]);
});
```

But I won't do that way because I will pass a random id. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

> you need to use `use` keyword `use ($var)`

```php
$var = 1; // <- outside scope variable
$response_send_email = Http::get('some url',function($http) use ($var) {
   $http->data(['id' => $var]);
});
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: it works, thank you for saving me from deadline !!!